# Enable wildcard in a WordPress Multisite (Sub-Domains)

Tags: multisite, subdomains

I have a WordPress Multisite (Sub-Domains option) with a few of sub-domains already working.

The site is located on a managed hosting with wildcard disabled.

So every time I want to create a sub-domain I'm forced to: a) configure the sub-domain on the hosting panel and b) set it up in WordPress backend

But now I need to create sub-domains on-demand; this involves the activation of the wildcard in the server. My provider can enable this functionality and is waiting for my confirmation.

My question is: can I activate wildcard quietly or I risk of breaking the site or its subdomains?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, wordpress do not actually have any knowledge of your DNS settings so no obvious reason for any change in them to have any impact (if you have some specially crafted htaccess or the likes of it, you should verify them they are not bound to specific subdomains)